# How generate SWIFT messages?

Tags: xsd, iso, financial, banking

I'am building module to generate SWIFT messages , are there any Java APIs to generate 20022 SWIFT messages, i don't create them manually 
mainly  I am interested in:

**• pain.008**

**• pacs.003**

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49956207/swift-messages-generate

Comment: @Armin Šupuk , it's different i want generate XML file  pain.008, pacs.003 from java classes